# AWS - Can we Load Yaml Files into DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way ( either through CLI - BatchWriteItem ) or something else to load yaml ( just like json ) to DynamoDB.

Answer (score 4):

Read the YAML into DICT/ JSON (if the structure is well known to you) using Python then export the data into DynamoDB. you can refer below code.

#### Parse YAML into

```
import yaml
with open('data.yaml','r') as stream:
     data = yaml.load(stream)
```

#### Inserting Data into DynamoDB

```
import boto3

# Get the service resource.
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('users')

table.put_item(
   Item={
        'username': 'janedoe',
        'first_name': 'Jane',
        'last_name': 'Doe',
        'age': 25,
        'account_type': 'standard_user',
    }
)
```

Comment: how you will preserve custom yaml tags (http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292)?

Answer (score 1):

You can load the yaml file as a string object (which might be enough for your use case), but DynamoDB won't be able to parse it like it would a json (it also can't parse a normal json either, it has to be marshalled with DynamoDB-specific json structure).